# Traversing Django models downstream in template language

Tags: python, html, django

I have the following model setup:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    val1 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    val2 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='model1')

class Model2(models.Model):
    val3 = models.BinaryField()
    model1_link = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model2')

class Model3(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    model2_link = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model3')

class Model4(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    model3_link = models.ForeignKey(Model3, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model4', null=True, default=None)
    pred = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In my HTML template, I have a section where I iterate over entries from Model1 (e.g. val1), and would like to be able for each value, to include field 'pred' from Model4. Models 1-4 are daisy-chained through their FK`s at the moment. Yes, I know I could just include FK in Model4 linking it to Model1, but from logical point of view, I do not prefer this option at the moment.

Anyway, expression like this does not get the job done on my end:

```
...
{% for entry in model1_entries %}
...
    {% if user.is_superuser and entry.model2.model3.model4.count > 0 %}
        something here
    {% endif %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

I figure the problem has something to do with the fact that call model1.model2 returns a set of all model2's related to model1, but I dunno how I can pick one in this expression and run with it through the rest of models before reaching #4.

Any ideas?

Comment: does your current method give you an error?

Comment: it doesn`t render the "something here" text inside of {% if ... %} expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a method to your `Model1` something like:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    val1 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    val2 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='model1')

    def get_model4_count(self):
        count = 0
        for m2 in Model2.objects.filter(model1_link=self):
            for m3 in Model3.objects.filter(model2_link=m2):
                count += Model4.objects.filter(model3_link=m3).count()
        return count
```

> your template says count, so this uses, count, but you can update to whatever you want.

At least that would allow you to write a test/debug that your method is returning the correct data, and allow you to easily use it in your template.

```
...
{% for entry in model1_entries %}
...
    {% if user.is_superuser and entry.get_model4_count > 0 %}
        something here
    {% endif %}
...
{% endfor %}
```